# How to calculate the similarity of two arrays accurately in python

Tags: python, classification, predict

I am involved in a difficulty in the case of classification. I have two arrays, the first is 'Actual', and the second is 'Predicted'. There are *3* class here.

```
A=np.array([1,1,1, 2,3])
P=np.array([1,1,2,3,3])
```

the above arrays mean that the third and fourth elements have not been accurately predicted. I am wondering when I calculate the mean accuracy between two arrays by the following code, It shows _ 0.59_:

```
np.mean(A==P)
>out: 0.59
```

But, when I calculate the accuracy for each class by the following code, it shows *0.57*:

```
count1=[]
for label in range(1,4):    
    count1.append(np.mean([(x == y)  for x, y in zip(A,P) if x==label]))     
count1
>out: [0.666666666667,0.0,1.0]   
np.mean(count1)
>out:0.54
```

The difference goes up further when the number of classes goes up.

Comment: You can't compute an overall average by averaging sub-averages.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really have to do with programming, but with calculating averages.

Suppose you have just two classes, and your data is  like this:

> Actual: [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
>
> Predicted: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

The accuracy in predicting class 1 is 100% and the accuracy in predicting class 2 is 0%.  The overall accuracy is 80%.  Now suppose your data is like this:

> Actual: [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
>
> Predicted: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

The accuracy in predicting class 1 is again 100% and the accuracy in predicting class 2 is again 0%.  But your overall accuracy is now 20%.  Clearly there is no way to derive the overall accuracy just from the accuracy percentages of the two classes.

You cannot compute an overall average accuracy just by knowing the per-class accuracy *rates* (i.e., percentages).  You need to know *how many* values were in each class, and weight the overall average accordingly.

You can of course compute the per-class accuracies and report them as separate information, and this may be useful.  In your case since you already know how to compute the overall accuracy, it's not clear why you need to use the per-class method to compute it at all.  Just compute the overall accuracy in the direct way, which already works.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, if I want to report the accuracy per class, the above code that I am doing is correct or nor?

Comment: Meanwhile, finally I will so cross validation. Hence, the point that you mentioned will be solved. I am wondering why the overall accuracy is not the same as the average of each classes.